# How to post data from my android app to server?

Tags: android, web-services, post

i want to send data from android application to server (.NET) but it doesn't work this is my code :

```
DefaultHttpClient hc=new DefaultHttpClient();  
ResponseHandler <String> res=new BasicResponseHandler();  
HttpPost postMethod=new HttpPost(myURl);  

postMethod.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, Boolean.FALSE);
postMethod.getParams().setBooleanParameter( "http.protocol.expect-continue", false );
postMethod.setHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json" );

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

json.put("TOKEN", channel_token).toString();
json.put("APPLICATIONDATASOURCEID", data_src_id).toString();
json.put("NEWSTITLE", Title_edittext.getText().toString().trim()).toString();
json.put("NEWSDETAILS", Details_edittext.getText().toString()).toString();      
json.put("ALERTSTARTSAT" , "12/03/2012/05/12");
json.put("ALERTENDSAT", "13/03/2012/06/12");
json.put("SENDPUSHNOTIFICATION", true);
json.put("EXPIREIMMEDIATELY", true);

Log.i("jason Object", json.toString());

StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
postMethod.setEntity(se);      

HttpResponse response = hc.execute(postMethod); 
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
String _response = convertStreamToString(is);
System.out.println("res  " + _response);
```

getting this as response from server **"Expectaions Failed"** . please tell me where is the problem.

Comment: are you passing correct parameters in your json string? whats your StatusCode?

Comment: parameters are correct, Status code means.

Comment: try postMethod.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, Boolean.TRUE);

Comment: is your webservice enabled with `[ScriptService]` to offer Json support? Status code means the response your webservice returns. You may get it by using `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();`. If the code is **200** then it means everything is **OK**, but in case your code is **500** then it means your webservice threw an exception due to **Internal Error**

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar still not working..

Comment: @Waqas i am getting response code 417.

Comment: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E417.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your Json request as below:

```
final int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 10000;  // = 10 seconds

HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(myURl);

//set post request type
request.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json; charset=utf-8");

//request result type
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
.
.
.
.
.
//and so on with rest of the code
```

Comment: if use your code setHeaders i am getting <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>,<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD> , Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2>, 02-28 15:43:44.007: I/System.out(1580): <hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p>  from response with code 400..

Comment: just disable this line `request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");` and see what does it say?

Comment: to me it seems like your webservice is not properly configured to offer **ScriptService**. Can you include your `web.config.xml` and your webservice `.cs` file in your question too?

Comment: that very big file check this link http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38493970/cs.txt and congig file http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38493970/Web.config this also http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38493970/CANewsItemContracts.cs

Comment: yes, my guess was right. Your webservice is not supporting Json connections. Read the following two links to set you webservice correctly

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45275/Create-a-JSON-WebService-in-ASP-NET-2-0-with-a-jQu

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a WSDL web service to post data on a .NET web server, because the .NET framework does not provide WSDL connectivity and it does not support direct `HttpPost(myURL)` like Java.

I hope [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112381/Step-by-Step-Method-to-Access-Webservice-from-Andr) will help you.

Comment: can you give me any tutorial. for this

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a tutorial, the Android SDK comes with a sample app called *Wikitionary*. It is a good example to understand HTTP Get with JSON.

Comment: in the above tutorial having how to get , my requirement how to post to server.